# Method not allowed show when new method add in snipe-it useing LARAVEL 5.4.29

Tags: php, laravel, methods, laravel-5.4

form action is /tags/uploadexcelfile

Controller/Api/TagController.php
Method create uploadexcelfile()
and

routes/api.php

/*--- Tags API ---*/

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'tags'], function () {

    Route::get('{item_type}/selectlist',
        [
            'as' => 'api.tags.selectlist',
            'uses' => 'TagsController@selectlist'
        ]

    );

    Route::post(
    'uploadexcelfile',
        [
        'as'  => 'api.tags.uploadExcelsheet',
        'uses' => 'TagsController@uploadExcelsheet'
        ]
    );
}); // Tags group

Route::resource('tags', 'TagsController',
    [
        'names' =>
            [   'uploader'=> 'api.tags.uploader',
               'uploadexcelfile'=>'api.tags.uploadexcelfile',
                'index' => 'api.tags.index',
                'show' => 'api.tags.show',
                'store' => 'api.tags.store',
                'update' => 'api.tags.update',
                'destroy' => 'api.tags.destroy'
            ],
        'except' => ['edit', 'create'],
        'parameters' => ['tag' => 'tag_id']
    ]
);// Tags Resource
```

then got network response check then error 
{"status":"error","messages":"Method not allowed","payload":null}
any have idea to why show this types of message

Answer (score 0):

You have uploadexcelfile route defined twice. Once in prefix tags section and other one in resource route tags.